# Pulseaudio with two sources, reduce volume for one

Tags: sound, python, firefox, pulseaudio

I'm watching NHL playoffs in Firefox, but during commercials I'm testing the music player I'm developing. I "unpause" my music player during commercials so there are two sound sources playing in pulseaudio. I would like my music player (python name `mserve`) to take "sound source priority" over Firefox.

Currently pulseaudio already seems to dim sound from Firefox a little bit when mserve is playing. The sound dimming is maybe 20 to 40%? How can I increase this such that pulseaudio is dimming Firefox say 60% to 80%?

If there is software that automatically recognizes when commercials start, eg sound gain increases or [inaudible to human-ear-sounds commercial tracking software](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2015/11/beware-of-ads-that-use-inaudible-sound-to-link-your-phone-tv-tablet-and-pc/) activated, that would save me from clicking "play" when commercials start and "pause" when hockey resumes.

**Note:** I assume it is `pulseaudio` and not `alsa` doing the heavy-lifting in the two input stream sound blender. I'm not looking for a GUI sound mixer, rather a bash or python solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

In Unix & Linux site I found this Q&A:

- [Command line per-application volume (maybe amixer or pactl?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208784/command-line-per-application-volume-maybe-amixer-or-pactl)

First get short list of sinks:

```python
$ pactl list short sink-inputs

1545    0   1083    protocol-native.c   float32le 2ch 48000Hz
1556    0   1083    protocol-native.c   float32le 2ch 48000Hz
1688    0   1083    protocol-native.c   float32le 2ch 44100Hz
1698    0   1455    protocol-native.c   s16le 2ch 44100Hz
```

Remove `short` from above command to confirm Firefox (in my case) is actually `1688`. My music player was just loaded and is the last input: `1698`. When pressing play on my music plyaer, I set Firefox volume to 40% with:

```python
$ pactl set-sink-input-volume 1688 40%
```

When pressing pause on music player I reset Firefox volume to 100% with:

```python
$ pactl set-sink-input-volume 1688 100%
```

---

### Long Answer

`40%` volume wasn't soft enough so `25%` was used.

There can be multiple instances of `Firefox` sound sources so all of them need to be muted.

Here's the final code:

```python
    def hockey_commercial(self):
        ''' 
        Commercial button plays music for 90 seconds then pauses.
        '''
        if self.play_hockey_active is True:
            return                          # Already running, don't restart
        self.play_hockey_active = True
        self.play_hockey_secs = 90
        self.play_hockey_remaining = self.play_hockey_secs
        self.play_soften_firefox()          # Soften volume of commercials
        self.play_hockey_tstart = time.time()
        if self.pp_state is "Paused":
            self.pp_toggle()                # Play music during commercials

    def play_soften_firefox(self):
        result = []
        self.play_firefox_indices = []
        result = os.popen('pactl list short sink-inputs') \
                          .read().strip().splitlines()
        count = len(result)
        if count < 2:
            print('result missing firefox:',result)
            return

        # Firefox may have multiple entries
        for line in result:
            sink = line.split('\t')[0]
            app = os.popen('pactl list sink-inputs | grep "Sink Input #' + \
                            sink + '" -A20 | grep application.name').read()
            if "Firefox" in app:
                self.play_firefox_indices.append(sink)
                result = os.popen('pactl set-sink-input-volume ' + \
                                    sink + ' 25%') \
                                    .read().strip().splitlines()
```

If you are curious what it looks like in action (be kind only my second program):

[image: mserve commercial.gif]

- The music player is paused while watching hockey
- When a commercial starts click the Commercial button with hockey stick character
- The button text changes to time remaining countdown
- Volume for Firefox is cut to 25% which is barely audible
- Music starts playing at normal volume
- When countdown hits zero music pauses and Firefox volume is restored
- You can still press pause/play during countdown